# equal() and equalsIgnoreCase() return false for equal strings

Tags: java, string, string-comparison

I'm working with eclipse IDE (Version: 3.4.2) on a mac and I have met the following issue.

When comparing between strings using equal() or equalsIgnoreCase() methods I receive false even when the string are equal. For example, the code below consider the following condition as false, even when values[0] = "debug_mode"

```
if (values[0].equalsIgnoreCase("debug_mode")) 
    debug_mode = true;
```

which is part of the following loop:

```
String value = dis.readLine();
String values[] = value.trim().split("=");
if (values.length >= 2)
{
    Config.prnt_dbg_msg(values[0] + "\t" + values[1]);
    if (values[0].equalsIgnoreCase("debug_mode")) 
        debug_mode = isTrue(values[1]);
    if (values[0].equalsIgnoreCase("debug_query_parsing")) 
        debug_query_parsing = isTrue(values[1]);
    if (values[0].equalsIgnoreCase("username")) 
        Connection_Manager.alterAccessParameters(values[1], null, null);
    if (values[0].equalsIgnoreCase("password")) 
        Connection_Manager.alterAccessParameters(null, values[1], null);
if (values[0].equalsIgnoreCase("database")) 
        Connection_Manager.alterAccessParameters(null, null, values[1]);
    if (values[0].equalsIgnoreCase("allow_duplicate_entries")) 
        allow_duplicate_entries = isTrue(values[1]);
}
```

I tried to use `value[0].equal("debug_mode")` and got the same result.
Does someone have any idea why?

Comment: what's the actual value of values[0]

Comment: Are you 110% sure `values[0]` contains a string with the value "debug_mode"? Print it to the console to be sure.

Comment: could you print values[0] before this if condition?

Comment: @Evan - even 120%, and that's the most that I can be. I observed this parameter during debug of the code, and in standard output.

Comment: if you're using a debugger, can you step into equalsIgnoreCase() and see what it's doing inside there?

Comment: i am also getting the same issue. how to compare these types of strings?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That would be very strange indeed :) Can you change the above code to this:

```
if ("debug_mode".equalsIgnoreCase("debug_mode")) 
    debug_mode = true;
```

confirm it works fine and then double check why your `values[0]` is not "debug_mode".

Here's what comes to my mind right now as a list of things to check:

- Check that `values[0].length() == "debug_mode".length()`
- I highly doubt, but let me put it on the table anyway - are you by any chance using Unicode?
- Can you print each character and do `.equals()` between that character and the respective character of the "debug_mode" string?
- If this is in a bigger project, can you do the same in a simple Java project and confirm it works there?

To clarify, the problem is actually using `DataInputStream.readLine`. From javadoc (http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6.0/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html):

```
readLine()
      Deprecated. This method does not properly convert bytes to characters. ...
```

It actually has to do with Unicode in a subtle way - when you do `writeChar` you actually write two bytes `0` and `97`, big-endian Unicode for the letter `a`.

Here's a self-contained snippet that shows the behavior:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class B {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String os = "abc";

    System.out.println("---- unicode, big-endian");
    for(byte b: os.getBytes("UTF-16BE")) {
      System.out.println(b);
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);

    for(char c: os.toCharArray()) {
      dos.writeChar(c);
    }

    byte[] ba = baos.toByteArray();

    System.out.println("---- ba");
    for(byte b: ba) {
      System.out.println(b);
    }

    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(ba);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bais);

    System.out.println("---- dis");
    String s = dis.readLine();
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println("String length is " + s.length() 
      + ", but you would expect " + os.length() 
      + ", as that is what you see printed...");
  }
}
```

Moral of the story - don't use deprecated api... Also, whitespace is the silent killer: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/whitespace-the-silent-killer.html

Comment: Well, you highly doubt it, but actually the problem was that I wrote to file using DataOutputStream.writeChar() instead of writeUTF(). and it did cause the problem.

Comment: Nothing to do with it. If writeUTF() worked and writeChar() didn't, he must have been *reading* with readUTF(), which certainly wouldn't work with data not written by writeUTF(). Unicode has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @EJP It's a mix of Unicode and deprecated API (the latter being more important) - see the edit.

Comment: So it had nothing to do with writeUTF() and nothing to do with deprecation either. It had to do with reading and writing using asymmetric methods. If you wrote with writeChars() you need to read with readChar(). If you wrote with writeUTF() you needed to read with readUTF(). If you wrote with PrintStream.println() you needed to read with readLine() (deprecated or not).

Comment: Not really - if you wrote by calling `writeChar` 5 times with last one being writing a new line character, you would expect that you could read all 5 characters into a string by calling `readLine` once. I would say it's a combination of all these factors and ambiguity of `readLine` (with respect to `writeUTF`). That's why `readLine` was deprecated. Definitively agree that you should try to be symmetric as much as you can.

Comment: No, you wouldn't expect that if you had read the Javadoc, where it clearly says it converst successive bytes to characters. Not byte pairs.

Comment: I don't say this deprecated implementation works as I would expect (clearly, it does not) - I said I would expect that if I used the method called `writeChar` and write `abcd\n` to a stream, I would expect the method called `readLine` to return a string `"abcd"`. It's not a good thing if you need to read javadoc to confirm that `readLine` does not read lines, which I would assume is a list of characters terminated by a new line, just because it doesn't consider characters the same way `writeChar` does. Fair enough remarks from your side - definitively, you are right on the implementation.

Comment: [new InputStreamReader(i, "utf8")] solved my problem too, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I have just had this exact same issue, using equalsIgnoreCase.

After hours of staring at the screen, debugging the code it dawned on me that my if statement had a ; at the end,

i.e.

```
if ("stupid".equalsIgnoreCase.("STupid");
{
     //it always gets here 

}
```

Hope this helps someone in future.

Comment: I thought you were a stupid because of that stupid error, but... I thought to myselft: "It's always human errors, so, let me check my code". And what happend? It was your same error!! :P And I have almost an hour with this

Comment: Similarly, I had a problem with trying to return from a method using this type of check. 
```if ("stupid".equalsIgnoreCase.("STupid")) return;```
I had to wrap the return block:
```if ("stupid".equalsIgnoreCase.("STupid")) { return; }```

Comment: You can also avoid this potential problem by putting the opening { on the same line as the IF Statement.  That's what I do.  That way if you add an unintended ";" anywhere you will almost certainly cause a compile problem due to bracket mismatch.

Answer (score 3):

I'm with the others, this is crazy and shouldn't happen. I agree that printing it out may help, but I'm going to assume you've tried that.

Is it possible it's a localization issue? That is, when you type in debug_mode in the editor (for the string) it's the string "debug_mode", but when you type the string in during execution the terminal is set to use a different language and you're getting a different (but identical looking) character?

To find out, loop through the string you get in and print out each character's integer value, and then do the same with your string that's hardcoded and see if they are the same.

```
String value = dis.readLine();
String values[] = value.trim().split("=");

System.out.println("Input:");

for (int i = 0; i < values[0].length(); i++) {
    System.out.print((int) values[0].charAt(i));
    System.out.print(' ');
}

System.out.println("Hardcoded:");

String debugMode = "debug_mode";

for (int i = 0; i < debugMode.length(); i++) {
    System.out.print((int) debugMode.charAt(i));
    System.out.print(' ');
}
```

Now for this to work, you'd have to type the code (or at least the debug_mode constant) so it has the same character set as you are using.

I'd be willing to bet a good sum of money this isn't the issue, but even if it isn't it should prove instructive and show you what is different.

Answer (score 2):

Try `compareToIgnoreCase`:

```
if (values[0].compareToIgnoreCase("debug_mode") != 0) 
    debug_mode = true;
```

And if *that* doesn't work, try `compareTo` instead.

And if *that* doesn't work, try:

```
String d = (String)values[0];
if (d.compareToIgnoreCase("debug_mode") != 0) 
        debug_mode = true;
```

And if *those* don't work, you have a *serious* Java issue. Either it's ancient or it doesn't like you.

Comment: There is no version of Java ancient or modern where these methods do not work correctly. It wouldn't have been able to compile itself for a start.

Answer (score 2):

**Although there are few very good** and correct answers above I would still like to mention **my personal experience so that anyone facing same problem** could get instant help from this answer.

I had two different string say **string A** and **string B** coming from diffrent sources, **they seemed identical to me** but **I was getting not equal for them on using equals method**

even on using **equalsIgnoreCase** gave me **false**

I was clueless because when I was printing those string (A & B) to check what they look like they were

```
String A is dsycuii343qzx899+ty=
String B is dsycuii343qzx899+ty=
```

so, **I then checked length of the two string** which gave me the clue

```
String A length = 20
String B length = 21
```

SO that means I might be missing something,

so what I did was

**I checked each String char by char**  and I got to know the problem

String A which seemed like `dsycuii343qzx899+ty=` was actually `dsycuii343qzx899+ty=\n`

i.e there was a `LF` (new line character) at the end which was noticed while Log check

hope it might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily run into this on Android with `SpannableString`, **like when a TextView has autolinking enabled**, for instance:

```
// Outputs "a string"
Log.d("test", "TextView text: " + textView.getText());

// Outputs "a string"
Log.d("test", "Text to match: " + "a string");

if( textView.getText().equals("a string") )
{
    // Won't get here
}
```

You can do a quick test to see what kind of string textView.getText() returns by doing:

```
Log.d("test", "String class: " + textView.getText().getClass().getSimpleName());
```

If indeed you've got a `SpannableString`, you simply need to call toString() on it for the if condition to be satisfied:

```
if( textView.getText().toString().equals("a string") )
{
    // We're here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On a different note, I had a JSP page having similar problems while comparing the retrieved "status" of a table:

```
try{



  // ID is a Primary Key (unique). STATUS column data type in DB: CHAR(20)
  rs = stmt.executeQuery("select STATUS from TEMP_TABLE WHERE ID='"+id+"'");

  while(rs.next()){

        status = (String) rs.getString("STATUS");

  }
   if ( status.equalsIgnoreCase("active") )
   {
          // Run some DB Queries
   } else {
           out.write("Page can't be accessed due to status : " + status);
   }
} catch(Exception e) { e.getMessage(); }
finally {
         //close all open objects
}
```

For reasons unknown to me it always hits the else block with message "Page can't be accessed due to status : active", though status is "active". I tried closing rs and stmt objects after each query before and after running this Query but that didn't helped. Eventually I changed my Query to

```
"select STATUS from TEMP_TABLE WHERE ID='"+id+"' where STATUS='ACTIVE'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be that although the actual `String` values are equal, their underlying `byte[]`'s may not be.

Try using this method to compare the two `byte[]`'s:

```
private String printBytes(String str) {
    byte[] bytes = str.getBytes(ENCODING);
    String output = "byte[";
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        output += Byte.toString(bytes[i]);
        if (i < bytes.length - 1) {
            output += ", ";
        }
    }
    output += "]";
    return output;
}
```

For example:

```
Charset ENCODING = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "string1: \"" + string1 + "\" - " + printBytes(string1));
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "string2: \"" + string2 + "\" - " + printBytes(string2));
```

This would enable a visual comparison. For long `String`s, you could compare the `byte[]`'s programmatically by iterating through both arrays at the same time and comparing the values.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just discovered one string had space before the string.
My strings were like " SUCCESS" and "SUCCESS", 
so it was returning `false`. I used:

```
 String st1=st.replaceAll("\\s","");
```

and thus problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

May be my answer is very later but it will be useful to someone.

Just trim() both the strings before comparison

```
       eg: if(data1.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(data2.trim()))
            {
                //This gives proper result
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be byte order mark: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8

just try str1.length() and str2.length() and if it is not the same do 
str1.charAt(0) and y=if you get something like *'\uFEFF' 65279* than that is your issue

Answer (score 0):

You should use the InvariantCulture parameter

```
String.Equals(string1, string2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```