# if statement not returning results

Tags: java, android

I'm sending a username and password to a website for authentication purposes, after all is said and done and I've retrieved the results from the server, I've placed the results in a variable called 'response' To this point everything is working correctly

```
response = sb.toString();
Toast.makeText(this,"Returned Value: "+ response,0).show();
```

The value seen in the above Toast is the value being returned by the php script. I've used both a valid user and an invalid user and the Toast displayed above shows the correct value (i.e. "Good Login" or "Login Failed") returned by the server. I want to test for those results so I can start the appropriate activity so I've put in some test "if" statements

```
if("Good Login".equals(response)){
 Toast.makeText(this, "Registered User" + mUsername, 0).show();
 }
if("Login Failed".equals(response)){
 Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry You're Not A Registered Subscriber",0).show();
 }
```

I'm getting nothing from either one. 
I've also tried

```
if(response.equals("Good Login")){
 Toast.makeText(this, "Registered User" + mUsername, 0).show();
 }
if(response.equals("Login Failed")){
 Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry You're Not A Registered Subscriber",0).show();
 }
```

With the same results. Not sure what else to test for. Is there a better way to test for success or failure?

Thanks

Comment: Have you debugged your code to see what **response** is when returned?

Comment: have you tried checking the actual value of response? Is it one of "Good Login" or "Login Failed"? Could it be an untrimmed string? such as "Good Login  " or " Login Failed"?

Comment: It might be an encoding issue, take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210713/equal-and-equalsignorecase-return-false-for-equal-strings

Comment: Have you tried a Sysout of your `response`? What does it show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debug (or print) the exact value of the `response` variable.

It is likely that there are whitespaces, so you may need to have  `response = response.trim()`

Comment: It was the trim(), once I trimmed it, everything worked
Thanks

Comment: @Hank good. Remember to mark the answer as accepted. And also remember to debug your programs if they don't work ;)

Comment: @Hank - when you output like your `Toast.makeText(this,"Returned Value: "+ response,0).show();` it helps to surround the output string with something -- I use square brackets -- `Toast.makeText(this,"Returned Value: ["+ response+"]",0).show();` then you'll see the leading and trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would return an integer error code rather than some string to check the error response.
2. Make sure you are returning the correct case, otherwise use equalsIgnoreCase

Answer (score 0):

The Java string equals function is fully case/spacing sensitive compare.

So if:`response = "Good Login "` or if it contains extra-spaces or non-printing characters then it will fail the test.

It would be a good idea to strip all whitespace, even the internal ones.  [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455794/removing-whitespace-from-strings-in-java) a SO question about doing just that.  Also use `String.equalsCaseInsesitive()` when doing that actual comparison.