# How to Compare two strings in android with optimization?

Tags: java, android, string, optimization, comparison

I already tried with string.equal function which will compare two strings, but what will be optimize way of doing same.
Suggestions are welcome.

Hi all got it may help others [What's the quickest way to compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805601/whats-the-quickest-way-to-compare-strings-in-java/) 
Thanks Saurabh for sharing link.

Comment: .equals is the best way of comparing two strings

Comment: *what will be optimize way of doing same* - `equals()` is the right way. You should choose what is right over what is fast.

Comment: But do we have any optimize way of doing same?

Comment: .equalsIgnorecase is also a function to compare Strings, same as .equals but it is case sensitive.

Comment: @RakshitNawani You mean case **in**sensitive.

Comment: Nope, need to check upper as well lower case letters.

Comment: Check this link it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210713/equal-and-equalsignorecase-return-false-for-equal-strings

Comment: If you've identified through profiling that string comparison is a bottleneck, an optimized way of doing it is to **not** do it: map the strings to numbers or bools or enums or etc. elsewhere, or compare strings less frequently somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me, You should use the equals() method of the String class to compare Strings.

```
if (xyz.equals("something")) { 
    //Do what you want if string is equal... 
}
```

see this [also..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805601/whats-the-quickest-way-to-compare-strings-in-java/)

Comment: Thanks @sourabh will try this.

Comment: @harsh..I have updated my answer

Comment: @harsh...you can also take help from this. http://www.coderanch.com/t/487350/Performance/java/compare-strings

Comment: thanks, will sure try this.

Comment: @harsh...So..have you found any conclusion???

Comment: nope, didn't try yet. Will update once done. Thanks @saurabh

Comment: link works, thanks for help.